# React input onChange won't fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I currently have this simple react app and I cannot get these onchange events to fire for the life of me.

```
var BlogForm = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        title: '',
        content: ''
    };
},
changeTitle: function(event) {

    var text = event.target.value;

    console.log(text);

    this.setState({
        title: event.target.value
    });
},
changeContent: function(event) {
    this.setState({
        content: event.target.value
     });
},
addBlog: function(ev) {
    console.log("hit hit");
},
render: function() {
    return (
                <form onSubmit={this.addBlog(this)}>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='picure'>Picture</label>
                        <div><input type='file' id='picture' value={this.state.picture} /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input className="form-control" type='text' id='content' value={this.state.title} onChange={this.changeTitle} placeholder='Title' />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input className="form-control" type='text' id='content' value={this.state.content} onChange={this.changeContent} placeholder='Content' />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button className="btn btn-default">Add Blog</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

    );
  }
});
```

Funny thing is when I use `onChange={this.changeTitle (this)}`, the event fires but the ev variable in the `changeTitle` function is not the correct one.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/dx8mq8dj/2/).

Comment: may I ask how you set it up, I knew this should have worked.

Comment: I copied your code exactly as you have it into the linked fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dx8mq8dj/2/

Comment: Stop rolling back constructive edits. I also recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
onChange={(evt) => this.changeTitle(evt)}
```

or:

```
onChange={this.changeTitle.bind(this)}
```

instead of:

```
onChange={this.changeTitle}
```

Comment: onChange={(evt) => props.onChangeDate(evt)} using this paradigm: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/flux-utils.html

Comment: If the function is bound correctly... why would all 3 of these not work?

Comment: Please explain why the top one does work and the bottom one does not

Comment: I know this is an old response, but you should never do the first two examples. It creates a major performance hit as it will create a done of additional renders. You should always use the third form.

Answer (score 5):

try moving the onChange to the parent div.. this worked for me

Comment: This works fine. But do you know why it works? Because many examples show that onChange should be put in the component or input you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, BUT I wanted to add that, if you are implementing the radio group button solution as provided in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/), make sure to remove the "data-toggle" option on the surrounding div:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
</div>
```

If you keep the data-toggle option as shown in the code above, the onClick and onChange events you added yourself to the input field will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

when you use :

```
onChange={this.changeTitle (this)}
```

react will call mentioned function automatically. you need to call the function like this:

```
onChange={this.changeTitle}
```

and also change your mentioned function to arrow function, otherwise you cant use "**this**" keyword in your function. in none arrow function "**this**" keyword is not object of your function so you cant access to your variables.
if you need to pass arguments to your function you should use other methods like `bind()`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not giving it an already given id. I'm not really why, but having duplicate ids for input with type file stops it from working.