# React range input IE11 onChange or onInput workaround

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

IE11 [uses onChange instead of onInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging) for `<input type='range'>` elements.

React [does not call either of these](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3096#issuecomment-237354102) in IE11.

The `onInput` works on FF, Chrome, and Edge, so that's OK.

Following the rabbit hole downwards leads [here](https://github.com/grommet/grommet-docs/pull/75) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/554#issuecomment-188288228), which suggest using `onMouseUp` or `onClick`, but I haven't gotten this working either.

I've tried various listener combinations to no avail. I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115571/react-input-onchange-wont-fire) (which didn't work either, of course).  Does someone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around - that IE uses `onchange` instead of `oninput`...

Comment: Looks like no, not the other way around? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2048 Haven't thought about this in a while though, will edit if in error!

Comment: I just messed around with it (without React) and am quite sure IE only uses `change`. I can't check if Edge is different but another answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19067260/3168107) also shows a diagram.

Comment: Ahh you're right, that very page says: `...you should use the oninput event, which will capture live updates in Firefox, Safari and Chrome...`  Updated. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I've settled on [react-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range) since it's lightweight, straightforward, and works.

`render()` in its [source](https://github.com/mapbox/react-range/blob/master/index.js) shows how it does it:

```
render: function() {
    var props = _extends({}, this.props, {
      defaultValue: this.props.value,
      onClick: this.onRangeClick,
      onKeyDown: this.onRangeKeyDown,
      onMouseMove: this.onRangeChange,
      onChange: function() {},
      ref: this.setRangeRef
    });
    delete props.value;
    return React.createElement(
      'input',
      props
    );
  }
```

---

**Update**

It appears this will be fixed in React 16: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/554#issuecomment-271579096

> If you look at the history above, you will see that the issue was closed by #5746.
>   If you open this PR, you will see that its milestone is set to 16.
>
> So the fix will be in 16, and we can’t put it in 15.x because it introduces a breaking change in behavior.
>
> I don’t know if it’s possible to backport it to 15.x. @jquense and @nhunzaker would likely be able to answer this.