# canvas drawImage() function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw an image (uploaded) on a canvas in react js.

```js
onChange = (e) => {
  var file = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
  const logo = new Image()
  logo.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas3")
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  logo.onload = async function() {
    canvas.height = logo.naturalHeight
    canvas.width = logo.naturalWidth
    ctx.drawImage(logo, 0, 0, logo.naturalWidth, logo.naturalHeight, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,
      ctx.canvas.height)
  }

  logo.src = this.state.logoFile
  const c = document.getElementById("canvas3")
  console.log(c.toDataURL())
}
```

```html
<label className="logoUpload">
    <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} required />
    <span>Upload logo</span>
</label>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

when I try to upload an image for the first time it doesn't work, But second time it draws. I don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: Just guessing but it may have to do with making logo.onload an async function.

Comment: I did that. Didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your onChange syntax to `onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}`

Another option might be to wrap the input in a `<div>` and move the onChange handler there.

reference: [React input onChange won't fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115571/react-input-onchange-wont-fire)

Comment: I tried it. But no luck. you should consider that it works fine when I upload the second time

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding await to `URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])` and made function async. The problem is I'm updating the img src without the url loaded. So, await worked.

Comment: URL.createObjectURL() is synchronous, awaiting for it will do nothing more than move to a microtask. You probably got fooled by something else in thinking it's what solved your issue, but it's clearly not.